# NoClassDefFoundError error while invoking method added using Java ASM

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I'm using ASM to inject code to methods:

```
    @Override
    public void visitCode() {
        visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "sssss/CopyOfsss", "foo", "()V");

        super.visitCode();
    }


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sssss/CopyOfsss
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Node.match(Pattern.java)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3345)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3760)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.match(Matcher.java:1127)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.matches(Matcher.java:502)
    at sssss.CopyOfsss.main(CopyOfsss.java:26)
```

please help~

Comment: Please read the documentation or manual, first.

Comment: This doesn't help man! Would you please figure out where and which chapter to read? If I changed the class to "java.land.System" and call the nanoTime, it works.

Comment: The `NoClassDefFoundError` (roughly) means the class was there on compile time, but not on runtime - do you perhaps have a classpath issue or a bungled JAR file here?

Comment: As you see above the "sssss/CopyOfsss" is the main class. It must be exist~

Comment: Which suggests it may be a classloader issue?  If `CopyOfssss` is loaded by a child classloader, makes a call in to a class loaded by its parent loader, and that class then tries to make a static call back to `CopyOfsssss` then it will fail (the child CL can see classes loaded by the parent but not vice-versa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I got my answer. This is because the injected class is loaded by bootstrap class loader, so the injected code can't call methods in "CopyOfsssss". Refer to [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/findingclasses.html). The solution is adding "-Xbootclasspath/a:/path/yourclass.lib" to the jvm argument. Note the "/a" after "Xbootclasspath" means appending.